# Шифр Цезаря Python

Tags: python, шифрование

Прошу помощи. Имеется задача:

https://stepik.org/lesson/Caesar-cipher-23896/step/1?adaptive=true&unit=6422

Шифр Цезаря заключается в замене каждого символа входной строки на символ, находящийся на несколько позиций левее или правее его в алфавите.

Для всех символов сдвиг один и тот же. Сдвиг циклический, т.е. если к последнему символу алфавита применить единичный сдвиг, то он заменится на первый символ, и наоборот.

Напишите программу, которая шифрует текст шифром Цезаря.

Используемый алфавит −− пробел и малые символы латинского алфавита: ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Формат ввода:
На первой строке указывается используемый сдвиг шифрования: целое число. Положительное число соответствует сдвигу вправо. На второй строке указывается непустая фраза для шифрования. Ведущие и завершающие пробелы не учитывать.

Формат вывода:
Единственная строка, в которой записана фраза: Result: "..." , где вместо многоточия внутри кавычек записана зашифрованная последовательность.

```
Sample Input 1:
3
i am caesar
Sample Output 1:
Result: "lcdpcfdhvdu"
```

Итак, вот как я ее решил:

```
a = int(input())
b = input()
c = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
res = []
len_c=len(c)
for i in b:
    res.append(c[(c.find(i)+a)%len_c]) 
print('Result: ', '"',''.join(res),'"', sep = '')
```

Интерпретатор выводит все верно. На сайте тест не проходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибся.

Comment: Видимо тесты хитрые. Правда делать заковыристый тест без какого-либо намёка на то, где ошибка - извращение ИМХО.

Comment: если честно, эти тесты отвратительные. Уже ДАЛЕКО не в первый раз с подобным сталкиваюсь. Приходится читать все коментарии, часто там кто-то догадывается, где именно проблема с тестами и подсказывает, что нужно сделать. Но в данном случае подсказок не нашел.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Caesar Cipher issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26371777/4279)

Comment: `b=b.strip()` не хватает.

Comment: сначала я хотел тоже написать функцию, но потом, как видите, я даже эту чертову строку примитивно написал. Мне кажется, что либо смещение где-то происходит неверно, либо проблема со строкой вывода.

Comment: похоже, дело в пробеле. в этом задании пробел тоже должен заменяться на символ. Я это понял после того, как вы сказали удалить пробелы. 'i am caesar' должно давать 'lcdpcfdhvdu', а у меня выводило 'ldpfdhvdu', то есть пробелы игнорировались. А вместо них должен быть символ 'c', если сдвиг вправо и символ 'x', если сдвиг влево

Comment: да, не хватало удаления пробелов. Только я сначала не мог этого понять. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой листинг для этой задачи:

```py
alpha = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
n = int(input())
s = input().strip()
res = ''
for c in s:
    res += alpha[(alpha.index(c) + n) % len(alpha)]
print('Result: "' + res + '"')
```

В вашем коде следует добавить удаление пробелов в начале и конце строки.

Comment: да, именно так. Я понял это слишком поздно просто. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

```
#modules
from colorama import *
from pyfiglet import *
init()
#title
title = figlet_format('Cesar')
print(Fore.WHITE)
print(title)
print(Fore.GREEN)
#main
while True:
    offset = int(input('Offset '))
    str = input('String ')
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    res = []
    ln = len(alphabet)
    n = '.\/[]{}()=-.,;:\'"1234567890~!`@#$%^&*<>?|=+_- '
    for l in str:
        if not l in n:
            res.append(alphabet[(alphabet.find(l)+offset)%ln])
        else:
            res.append(l)
    print(''.join(res))
```

Этот код отсеивает символы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```py
alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = 3
s = "i am caesar"
subst = dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[key:]+alphabet[:key]))
res = ''.join(map(subst.__getitem__, s)) 
print('Result: "' + res + '"') # Result: "lcdpcfdhvdu"
```

или

```py
subst = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[key:]+alphabet[:key])
res = s.translate(subst)
```