# IndexError: string index out of range при попытке создания шифра Цезаря

Tags: python, шифрование

Пытаюсь сделать криптовальщик. Суть его заключается в том чтобы зашифровать слово по шифру Цезаря. Знаю что есть множество библиотек для этого дела, но я попытался сам.

Вопрос в том, в чем моя ошибка?

```
a = 0   # a это счетчик, при каждой замене буквы счетчику прибавляется единица

# игнорируем регистр, это слово которое нужно зашифровать
word_crypt = input("Ce cuvint doresti sa criptezi? ").lower()
while True:
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   #английский алфавит
    word_list = list(word_crypt)   #делаем список из изначального слова
    aa = word_crypt[a]  #получаем строку первого индекса изначального слова
    bb = alphabet.find(aa) #находим это строку в алфавите, получаем индекс
    cc = alphabet[bb+2]  #находим букву на 2 позиции впереди этой буквы
    a = a + 1 #прибавляем 1 счетчику
    if a >= 0:  #если счетчик больше или равен нолю
        word_new = word_list[word_list.index(aa)] = cc #заменяем первую букву на +2 в алфавите

        # вроде как делаем новую строку которая равне верхней, это строка будет изначальным словом с 1 измененной буквой
        word_list = word_new
        list_final = [] #пустой список
        list_final.append(word_list) #прибавляем к этому списку замененную букву

    # если счетчик плюс 1 больше длины слова, то принтим список(криптованное слово) и останавливаем цикл
    elif a + 1 > len(word_crypt):
        print(list_final)
        break
```

Но, при запуске кода, выдаёт такую ошибку на строчке с `cc = alphabet[bb+2]`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 26, in <module>
File "python", line 7, in crypt_one
IndexError: string index out of range
```

По моей логике, этот код должен работать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Шифр Цезаря Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594690/%d0%a8%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%a6%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-python)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это будет уже не «я попытался сам»

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле эта ошибка не единственная:

```
# изначально можно обойтись без счетчика
a = 0

# данный цикл можно заменить на `for`
while True:

# алфавит задается каждую итерацию цикла, его можно вынести за него
alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

# если ищем индекс, то нужно и использовать `index`
bb = alphabet.find(aa)

# здесь не хватает деления по модулю на длину алфавита 
# чтобы не уйти за его границы
cc = alphabet[bb+2]  # это причина первой ошибки

# счетчик все время больше или равен нулю
if a >= 0:

# охохох, что здесь?
word_new = word_list[word_list.index(aa)] = cc

# список все время будет обнуляться, даже если повезет и программа
# исполнится корректно, на выходе все равно будет только один символ
list_final = []  

# это условие не сработает никогда, 
# из-за этого счетчик уйдет за границу `word_crypt`
elif a + 1 > len(word_crypt):
```

В коментариях к коду постарался описать все недочеты.
Также добавляю свой вариант [шифра Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F)

```
class CaesarCipher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '

    def Encrypt(self, text, shift=2):
        cipher = ''
        for ch in text.lower():
            cipher += self.alphabet[(self.alphabet.index(ch) + shift) % len(self.alphabet)]
        return cipher

    def Decrypt(self, cipher, shift=2):
        text = ''
        for ch in cipher.lower():
            text += self.alphabet[(self.alphabet.index(ch) - shift) % len(self.alphabet)]
        return text


# по умолчанию сдвиг на 2 буквы вперед
cipher = CaesarCipher().Encrypt("Ce cuvint doresti sa criptezi")
print(cipher)                          # egbewxkpvbfqtguvkbucbetkrvgak
print(CaesarCipher().Decrypt(cipher))  # ce cuvint doresti sa criptezi

# ибо свое значение сдвига, например, 3
cipher = CaesarCipher().Encrypt("Ce cuvint doresti sa criptezi", 3)
print(cipher)                             # fhcfxylqwcgruhvwlcvdcfulswhbl
print(CaesarCipher().Decrypt(cipher, 3))  # ce cuvint doresti sa criptezi
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в строке `bb = alphabet.find(aa)` находите положение буквы в алфавите, соответственно переменная `bb` может принимать значения от `0` до `25`. Допустим `bb = 25`. Вы в строке `cc = alphabet[25+2]` обращаетесь к 28 символу алфавита, (которого нет) и получаете выход за границу списка. Исправление на `cc = alphabet[(bb+2)%25]`, по моему, должно исправить ситуацию.

Comment: к сожалению, нечего не поменялось. Выдает такую же ошибку. Спасибо за попытку помочь.