# на что можно это заменить

Tags: python

```py
p = input('Введите текст шифрования и нажмите Enter \n'
              ' >>>>  ')
p = p.replace("а", "б") and p.replace('б', 'в') and p.replace('в', 'г') \
and p.replace('г', 'д') and p.replace('д', 'е') and p.replace('е', 'ё') \
and p.replace('е', 'ж') and p.replace('ж', 'з') and p.replace('з', 'и') \
and p.replace('и', 'й') and p.replace('й', 'к') and p.replace('к', 'л') \
and p.replace('л', 'м') and p.replace('м', 'н') and p.replace('н', 'о') \
and p.replace('о', 'п') and p.replace('п', 'р') and p.replace('р', 'c') \
and p.replace('c', 'т') and p.replace('т', 'у') and p.replace('у', 'ф') \
and p.replace('ф', 'х') and p.replace('х', 'ц') and p.replace('ц', 'ч') \
and p.replace('ч', 'ш') and p.replace('ш', 'щ') and p.replace('щ', 'ъ') \
and p.replace('ъ', 'ы') and p.replace('ы', 'ь') and p.replace('ь', 'э') \
and p.replace('э', 'ю') and p.replace('ю', 'я') and p.replace('я', 'а')

print(p)

break
```

Comment: Это закомментированный код. Его нужно просто удалить.

Comment: Если же его раскомментировать, то окажется, что результатом `p` будет последняя часть условия: `p.replace('я', 'а')`. Если Вы хотите заменять буквы, то делайте это в цикле. Желательно с использованием словаря. `break` вообще не нужен.

Comment: Кстати, это шифр Цезаря с единичным сдвигом. Решение легко находится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594946/339283.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
s = input().strip()
res = ''
for c in s:
    res += alpha[(alpha.index(c) + 1) % len(alpha)]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Всю эту простыню можно заменить на

```
p = p.replace('я', 'а')
```